# AJAX auto reload table won't execute

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to work on a AJAX auto reload script that reloads the PHP script everyfew seconds

Here is the script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function reload() {
            $('#autoload').load('assets/php/get-emails.php');           
    }
    setInterval(reload, 1000);
});
            
</script>
```

HTML Table code (the is th):

```
<table class="table" style="background-color :1c1f20;" id="inbox autoload">
<thead>
<tr style="color: grey;text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;">
<the scope="col"> From </th> 
<the scope="col">Title</th>            
<the scope="col">details</th>   
<the scope="col">forward</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>   
<div>
<?PHP
 DisplayEmails($_COOKIE['t_email_address_1']);
?>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But it doesn't work and I tried every solution I found.

BTW: the get-emails prints out  ...  tags out for a table.

And the autload id is in the table tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What happens on the page? What do you see in your browser's dev tools network tab? Do you see any errors? What does the request return? Also share your table's HTML, so we can better help you

Comment: You cannot have a `<div>` as a child of `<tbody>`, only `<tr>`

Comment: `id="inbox autoload"`?

Comment: Hey, after the time nothing happens on the page. The dev tools network tab doesn't request anything after the given time. I want to update the table with new emails (tr tags). But there are no errors in the console by dev tools...

Comment: Ok, it does not load because there is no element with id `autoload`, as pointed out by @LawrenceCherone. jQuery can't find it, so it does not bother making the request. It has to be `id="autoload"`, not `id="inbox autoload"`

Answer (score 0):

A html id can only be one, you can't have a separation of inbox and autoload, "id" in html does not work like html classes.
so you can either make use of classes or you specify just one name for id I.E "inbox" or "autoload", but not both, at best you can join the id like this "inbox-autoload"

Worth noting:

kindly make use of the jQuery $.on(), if you want to deal with auto-generated data or tag that didn't previously exist in the DOM on load, but it is rather dynamically loaded via AJAX(this simply assumes, your autoload html tag, did not exist from the initial page load)